# Mule: Database Merge not working with Query Type as 'Update'

Tags: database, mule

I am setting my MERGE statement in a dynamic query in Mule as follows:

```
    <db:update config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
      <db:dynamic-query><![CDATA[BEGIN MERGE INTO 
            TBL1 X1 USING
```

But I get the following Error:

Query type must be one of '[UPDATE, STORE_PROCEDURE_CALL, TRUNCATE, MERGE]' but was 'DDL' (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException). Message payload is of type: LinkedHashMap
Type                  : org.mule.api.MessagingException

I am setting the Update on the Query, still it says I have to use Update, the other options like TRUNCATE or MERGE I don't see at all.

I am using the Enterprise Edition here.

Comment: Can you upload your complete <db>...</db> xml? Seems like an attribute is missing or set improperly

Answer (score 1):

**db:update should start with MERGE**

You should remove the `BEGIN` you put in the SQL Statement, make sure it starts with `MERGE`, the rest of it looks good.